# Change 'createOptions' of edgeAgent and edgeHub using code

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

Is there a way to make changes to the **createOptions** of the **"edgeHub"** module **using code**?

I know how to do it using the Azure Portal: `Set Modules -> Runtime Settings -> CreateOptions`

[image]

**Is there an API that I could use for that?**

Example: The AzureCLI has `az iot edge deployment create` (but it does not let me edit system modules:

`az iot edge deployment create --deployment-id $deploymentId --hub-name $hubName --content $contentPath --target-condition $targetCondition --layered`

Maybe the C# Client has a way to do it or there is a REST API accessible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use this command and you are good to go: `az iot edge set-modules --device-id $deviceId --hub-name $hubName --content $deploymentFilePath`
Also check this link at https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/iot-edge/how-to-deploy-modules-cli

Answer (score 0):

`deployment.template.json` has a key called [createOptions](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/iot-edge-sample-c/blob/master/deployment.template.json#L26) where you can mention the same values as done in the portal. And then you can build and push your container image on container registry. After that, deployment can be done for that edge device.